# Cannot Import Counter is encountered in python 2.7.3 on CSH

Tags: python

I am using UNIX's cShell in my Windows 7 OS.
When I am executing a prog. it shows an error every time :`can not import name Counter`.
though I have mentioned in the script `from collections import Counter`.
I am using `Python 2.7.3`, then why this problem is persisting.

Comment: The error is not in csh as you say in the title, it's in Python as you have properly tagged.

Comment: Double check that you are using Python 2.7 - Counter is relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that for some reason the path to the collections library is not being correctly detected by python. See the official documentation's section on the [PYTHONPATH environment variable](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), find the library's location on your computer, and manually add it to the path.

Comment: Can also print out the value of `sys.path` at the beginning of the program to see if it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be solved after rebooting if you have freshly installed newer version of python. or other options as presented in other answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11153766/1436658