# pycrypto error....ImportError: cannot import name Counter

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to design AES CTR encryption/ decryption program in python using pycrypto++. But every time I am running below code:

```
decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=Counter.new(64, prefix=nonce))
```

I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aes-ctr.py", line 3, in <module>
  from collections import Counter
ImportError: cannot import name Counter
```

nonce is given by me.Please help me. My python version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two things that may cause this.

Either you've made a file called "collections.py" and it's hiding the library module of the same name. If so, rename it.

If not, you've somehow messed up your python versions. `Counter` should definitely be in python 2.7.3. Try reinstalling python and double check what version you're actually running (e.g. by printing out `sys.version_info` somewhere inside your program).

To diagnose the problem, try `import collections` and `print collections.__file__`. It should be in the python2.7 directory. Open the file and search for `class Counter`.

Comment: above issue was restolved after rebooting but now I am facing other issue with line: `from Crypto.Util import number`  it is giving following error: `ImportError: No module named Crypto.Util`

Comment: @pratibha Do you have multiple versions of python installed? Are you sure your script is run by the python version for which you've installed the Crypto package?